# How do you call a Go function in VSCode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode and the Go plugin installed.  I am trying to call this function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printHello() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

1. First, I opened the VSCode Command Palette and chose `Go: Test file`, which threw a `No tests found. Current file is not a test file.` error.
2. Then I opened the VSCode Command Palette and chose `Go: Test function at cursor` - this threw the same error.
3. Then I created a sibling file with a `_test.go` naming convention:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    msg, err := printHello()
}
```

This threw a build error: `c:\path\to\my_test.go:8:18: main() used as value`.

4. Then I added a simple `return` statement, which threw the following error:

```
go: cannot find main module, but found .git/config in c:\path\to\my_folder
    to create a module there, run:
    cd ..\.. && go mod init
```

5. I right-clicked the function name itself and chose the `Go: Debug Test at Cursor` function, and the `Go: Generate unit tests for function` option, which in-turn prompted me to install several other VSCode plugins, and prompted me to upgrade Go itself. The previous two Command Palette options started to fail with `ENOENT` errors, so I restarted VSCode, and got a new test function. I opened up the VSCode Debug Console but it wouldn't let me start a session there.
6. I right-clicked the parent folder and chose the `Open in Integrated Terminal` option, which started a WSL session - `cd ..\.. && go mod init` threw errors related to `GOPATH`:

```
 me@COMPUTER:/mnt/c/path/to/my_folder$ go mod init
-bash: /c/go/bin/go.exe: No such file or directory
```

7. I tried determining what the WSL `GOPATH` was pointing to via `Go: Show current GOPATH` - it actually turned out that *both* the WSL and VSCode `GOPATH`s were incorrect.
8. I opened up a normal Command Prompt which had the correct `GOPATH` and I fired off `go mod init` which errored out (the previous guidance from VSCode was incorrect):

```
go: cannot determine module path for source directory C:\path\to\my_folder (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)

Example usage:
        'go mod init example.com/m' to initialize a v0 or v1 module
        'go mod init example.com/m/v2' to initialize a v2 module

Run 'go help mod init' for more information.
```

9. I decided on a `v2` Go module initialization (I don't know why one would opt for `v0` or `v1`), which created a `go.mod` in the root directory of my project, but now I am seeing the following package-related errors:

```
gopls requires a module at the root of your workspace.
You can work with multiple modules by opening each one as a workspace folder.
Improvements to this workflow will be coming soon, and you can learn more here:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md.
```

How do I call a Go function in VSCode?

Comment: `printHello` returns nothing so you cannot assign its result to `msg, err := `

Comment: Even if `printHello` returned 2 values, the code is invalid because of the unused variables. I suggest working through the introductory Go documentation to get a handle on the basics of the language.

Comment: @zerkms @JimB These are just examples.  Throwing in an empty `return` throws `go: cannot find main module`. The VSCode Debug Console will not let me start a session to run `cd ..\.. && go mod init`.

Comment: @JimB It's starting to seem like VSCode doesn't really run Go code out-of-the-box.  I was hoping it would at least perform basic build and configuration steps automatically so that I can run my function.  Is there a better IDE to use, or are these sorts of things just regular growing pains in the larger Go ecosystem?

Comment: VSCode isn't really an IDE, but it has plugins to do various functions. The majority of Go developers don't rely on a complete IDE to do everything for them, the cli tooling is very simple and complete. I've never used anything but vim myself.

Answer (score -1):

The answer turns out to be:

1. You need to create a `*_test.go` unit test harness and install more adjacent VSCode plugins.
2. You need to run `go mod init blah` somewhere outside of VSCode. `blah` is the name of your module. VSCode is unreliable with respect to the `GOPATH`.
3. There is a gotcha here where if you run `go mod init main`, this is valid but VSCode will throw misleading errors later on (see https://appliedgo.net/testmain/). You have to name it something else.
4. You need to re-open the VSCode workspace in a way such that `go.mod` is in the root of the workspace, or else VSCode runs into relative pathing errors.